# Eclipse ADT Bundle - Can it generate Include path automatically?

Tags: android, android-ndk, adt

When I import my existing project into Eclise ADT Bundle for Win64([here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)), Project Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols doesn't have any include folders.

In my opinions, since NDK is already set in the environment, at least it should include ${ANDROID_NDK}\platforms\android-xx\arch-arm\usr\include folder in the "include directories". I guess it would satisfy at least half of NDK developers. and $ANDROID_NDK$ has to be set manually even!

Does anyone know how to set this to automatic generation? Many thanks.
PS: Linux version of the ADT bundle seems to generate this automatically, by default.